# Angular 6 Date picker(disabled input field) is not binding to form object

Tags: angular, angular-material

> I am new at angular. I am using **angular material(7.0.2)**. I tried the below form has **date picker** with **disabled** input. On submitting **date** is not appearing in **f.value(object of form)**. If I **remove disabled** from an input field then it works perfectly. I don't know it is due to disabled or something else is the reason. In short, due to disabled it does not able to return form object.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="AddEvent(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput ngModel name="date" [matDatepicker]="picker"  disabled required>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker disabled="false" touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

> Here is a code of TS file

```
export class CreateEventComponent implements OnInit {

  isLogin:boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  AddEvent(f)
  {
    f.value.date =f.value.date.toDateString();
    console.log(f.value);

  }

}
```

> Output:

```
Null object
```

Comment: Please Check Component.ts file and output file for any confusion.

Comment: Screenshots of your IDE are most unhelpful. To help us to help you, please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

In this case a stackblitz example would be a very good idea (https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience I am new at StackOverflow

Comment: Your code does not work because `ERROR TypeError: f.value.date.toDateString is not a function`. If you remove that statement it works fine. Besides that, it doesn't make sense to have a disabled datepicker input field with an enabled datepicker popup. Try making the input `readonly` instead of disabled - I think that's probably what you really want anyway. Otherwise, please explain what your are trying to do.

Comment: ya making it read-only making sense. it worked thanks